# Лицензия windows 10 на ноутбуке

Tags: windows-10, лицензирование

Планирую купить ноутбук с предустановленной Windows 10. Модель идет без SSD, но я хочу его сразу же прикупить отдельно.

Вопрос: с какими проблемами я могу столкнуться при установке и активации Windows 10 на SSD и форматированием основного HDD c предустановленной ОС.

После данных действий я же не теряю лицензию?

Да и вообще в каком виде она активируется, так же как и раньше, вводом ключа или же как то привязывается к железу?

**PS**: вот как я себе представил последовательность:

- купил ноут, ssd;
- день, два посмотрел все ли нормально в отношении качества;
- качаю образ-инсталяшку win10 на флешку;
- ставлю ssd;
- форматирую основной hdd;
- запускаю установку win10 c флешки на sdd;
- вот после этого как то же она должна быть активирована?

Comment: по своему опыту - если второй диск не будет использоваться для "нелегальной установки", то проблем не должно быть. В худшем случае при установке придется позвонить в саппорт и просто подтвердить установку.

Comment: Если делать перенос с помощью специализированных программ, которые могут идти в комплекте с диском или качаться с сайта производителя, то проблем не будет вообще. Сейчас много производителей этим заморачиваются (Samsung, Intel), потому что знают для чего в основном покупаются диски.

Comment: @Zefick, а если акронисом каким-нибудь?

Comment: @Zefick да в принципе так как винт не забит моей инфой, то ничего переносить не надо же...или вы имеете ввиду перенос чего то еще?

Comment: @KoVadim ну вот раньше допустим у меня покупался ноут и на нем была наклейка с ключом активации, сейчас так же?

Comment: Я не покупал ноутов с 10 виндой. Не могу сказать наверняка. Но у меня есть два ноута, которые проапргейдились до 10 винды, потом там был заменен винт на ssd. Ни на одном винда не ругается, что она "какая то неправильная".

Comment: @KoVadim устанавливали с флешки? то есть после установки на ssd вы никаких активаций в ручную не делали?:)

Comment: @droid нет наклеек еще с 8 винды на ноутах, покупал ноут с 8 виндой летом 2015 - наклейки нет

Comment: @tCode то есть если наклеек нет, то привязка идет либо к железу, либо к учетке(что то такое слышал)

Comment: На одном ноуте я переносил с помощью gparted рабочую систему (правда потом выяснилось, что она не сильно хотела, что бы там был ещё grub, пришлось утихомирить винду). На втором просто копированием диска. Без флешек.

Comment: @droid я думаю что к железу, только не понятно к какому, к харду или к матери?

Comment: @KoVadim ооо, а просто в лоб скопировать я даже и не думал))эт кстати как вариант)

Comment: Думаю, там все сложнее. Из того, что мне известно, в 7 было так - если поменялось до трех элементов (винт/видеокарта/звуковая), и какое то время не меняется, то все ок, оно признается "родным". А вот если поменять много (например, материнку сразу), то тут винда бушует.

Comment: @KoVadim ну у меня то всего один элемент(sdd), и просто его добавление...хотя с скорее в этом разрезе это все таки замена))

Comment: Я бы сделал перенос даже если нет никакой своей инфы. Всё-таки сейчас на ноутбуке OEM-версия системы, сделанная производителем под него. Придётся где-то искать именно такую же версию. А это либо покупка коробки, чего вы делать не станете, либо скачивание из интернета непонятно откуда взятых образов, потому что сами Microsoft официально их уже не раздают за просто так.

Comment: @Zefick то есть есть специальное ПО для переноса win c одного диска на другой? простое копирование может не прокатить?

Comment: Смотря что понимать под копированием. Просто через буфер обмена конечно же не прокатит, потому что система это не просто набор файлов, которые можно спокойно таскать. Там есть сюрпризы в виде хотя бы символьных ссылок на файлы, которые скопируются неправильно, либо вообще будут указывать на файлы со старого диска и после его форматирования всё перестанет работать. Программы для клонирования дисков, например акронис или программа с диска производителя SSD, учитывают все тонкости.

Comment: @Zefick, вот как раз для клонирования дисков вряд ли учитывают. А для переноса - должны бы. Но вполне возможно, что и клонирования хватит.

Comment: @droid, думаю, цитату с майкросовта надо в ответ, а не в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну эт к Andrew Hobbit, пусть он себе в ответ добавит, после я из вопроса удалю.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самому стало интересно. Позвонил в службу поддержки 8-800-200-8001. Там подсказали, что OEM лицензия на "десятку" привязывается к материнской плате, все остальное можно менять. Активация, чаще всего, проходит автоматически, ключ извлекается из микросхемы энергонезависимой памяти (BIOS/UEFI ?). Посмотреть его можно с помощью специальной программы с сайта MS или командной строки. Если активация автоматом не сработала, то звоним в MS по горячей линии и по этому ключу активируемся.
Т.е. можно смело делать образ с диска, раскатываеть его на SSD, и активация даже слететь не должна. Можно с сайта MS скачать оригинальный образ 10-ки (такой же редакции) и установить его на SSD. Обещают, что в большинстве случаев активация пройдет автоматически.

Подтверждение в [FAQ Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/faq):

> **Мое устройство поставлялось с предустановленной Windows. Могу ли я скачать и установить образ диска с этого сайта?**
>
> Перед тем как использовать копии операционных систем, представленные
>   на этом сайте, для установки, переустановки или восстановления на
>   устройствах с предустановленными операционными системами, ознакомьтесь
>   с настраиваемыми драйверами и приложениями, созданными специально для
>   вашего устройства, на сайте изготовителя и торгового посредника.
>   Использование копий операционных систем, представленных на этом сайте,
>   для установки, переустановки или восстановления может аннулировать
>   ваше соглашение о поддержке, заключенное с изготовителем и торговым
>   посредником. Все драйверы и программы, установленные изготовителем
>   устройства или торговым посредником, могут быть удалены в ходе
>   установки.
>
> **Я понимаю риск. Будет ли образ диска с этого сайта правильно установлен на устройство, которое поставлялось с предустановленной
>   операционной системой?**
>
> Устройства с предустановленными операционными системами Windows 8.x и
>   Windows 10. Вы можете скачать и использовать образ диска с этого сайта
>   на своем устройстве, и он будет установлено правильно. В большинстве
>   случаев вам не потребуется вводить ключ продукта во время установки,
>   так как он внедрен в системную плату. Однако после установки
>   устройство НЕ будет содержать предустановленных специализированных
>   драйверов и программного обеспечения изготовителя. *Если вам будет
>   предложено ввести ключ продукта во время установки, обратитесь к
>   разделу "Как найти свой ключ продукта Windows?", который находится
>   выше.

Comment: собственно о чем я и говорил.

Comment: `(такой же редакции)` имеется ввиду home/ultimate итд?

Comment: кстати хз хз на счет материнки, вспомнил я, что летом менял мать и винда нормально после смены себя чувствовала, хотя материнка БУ была...

Comment: @tCode ну может ключ где то закешировался в системе, и если переустановить ОС, то она уже активирована не будет) хотя эт вряд ли) вот полюбому еще как то к их учеткам привязка идет

Comment: Кстати, если в ноуте стоял HDD, то возможно производитель даже не поскупился оставить там скрытый раздел восстановления, откуда при желании можно восстановить систему на новый диск уже в активированном виде. Правда скрипт восстановления по умолчанию может оказаться тупым и восстановить систему на изначальный диск ничего не спрашивая. Так что это тоже морока.

Comment: @Zefick да, у меня на старом ноуте такой раздел был, правда так и не разу я им и не воспользовался)